# How do you link a minecraft microsoft account to twitch account

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, streaming, twitch

I want to stream on twitch but I don't have a Mojang account I have a Microsoft account and I can't link my accounts together does anyone know how to fix this and connect the accounts?

Comment: Do you own Minecraft? If so, what version did you buy and when did you buy it? You may already have a Mojang account, it is your minecraft login credentials.

Comment: If you bought Minecraft after 2020, you should have a Microsoft account and not a Mojang account.

Answer (score 1):

The method for streaming on Twitch directly from Minecraft is highly outdated. I suggest using OBS Streamlabs for streaming to twitch, [download](https://streamlabs.com/). Sorry for not giving you the answer you wanted, but this is the best way to stream.

Comment: The question in and of itself is relevant nonetheless, as services such as Overwolf Curseforge may need to find your Minecraft Microsoft account via a linked Twitch account.

Comment: The user said they wanted to stream

Comment: I do agree for the specific needs of the asker, but from my understanding, the whole purpose of questions remaining accessible is that others with a similar question (including if they have a different purpose behind the same question, if possible) can use it to solve their problems, as long as they have the same TL;DR. Of course, it's debatable whether the TL;DR includes the purpose of the account linking.